# Anotación @Calculation no funciona en OpenXava

Tags: java, openxava

En mi aplicación OpenXava la anotación @Calculation no funciona.

Aquí el código de mi @Embeddable que usa @Calculation:

```
import java.math.*;
import java.time.*;
import javax.persistence.*;
import org.openxava.annotations.*;
import lombok.*;

@Getter @Setter
@Embeddable
public class Payment {

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @DescriptionsList
    Paymentfrequency paymentFrequency;

    LocalDate firstPaymentDate;

    @Stereotype("MONEY")
    BigDecimal paymentAmount;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @DescriptionsList
    Methodofpayment methodOfPayment;

    @ReadOnly
    @Stereotype("MONEY")
    @Calculation("paymentAmount * paymentFrequency.frequencyPerYear")
    BigDecimal annualContribution;
}
```

Y éste el código para mi entidad con la colección de embebidos:

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import lombok.*;

@Entity @Getter @Setter
public class Paymentfrequency extends GenericType {

    int frequencyPerYear;

    @ElementCollection
    @ListProperties("firstPaymentDate, paymentAmount, paymentFrequency,
methodOfPayment, annualContribution")
    Collection<Payment> payments;

}
```

Y éste el resultado:

[image: Colección donde @Calculation no funciona]

Fijaos como la última columna (annualContribution) no se recalcula cuando los operandos cambian.

¿Por qué no funciona @Calculation en este caso?

Answer (score 0):

@Calculation sólo funciona si todos los operandos están presentes en la interfaz de usuario. En tu caso paymentFrequency.frequencyPerYear no se visualiza dado que paymentFrequency es una referencia visualizada como @DescriptionsList.

No te preocupes, simplemente usa una propiedad calculada Java convencional en su lugar. De esta forma:

```
@Stereotype("MONEY")
@Depends("paymentAmount, paymentFrequency.id")
public BigDecimal getAnnualContribution() {
    // Deberías refinar este código para tratar los nulos
    return getPaymentAmount().multiply(getPaymentFrequency().getFrequencyPerYear()); 
}
```

Aprende más sobre las propiedades calculadas aquí:

https://openxava.org/OpenXavaDoc/docs/basic-business-logic_es.html

Comment: En la comunidad creo que se puede responder uno a sí mismo, pero si lo haces, supongo que sería conveniente que lo mencionaras tipo: "Me respondo a mí mismo" y no hacerlo como si respondiera una tercera persona. un saludo

Comment: Responder tu misma pregunta no solo esta permitido, sino que es algo que StackOverflow recomienda: https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/ De hecho, cuando añades una pregunta hay un checkbox que dice "Responder tu misma pregunta", el cual yo marco y así puedo poner la pregunta y respuesta a la vez. Lo de poner "Me respondo a mi mismo" me parece redundate y lo de responder como si fuera una tercera persona me gusta. Estoy moviendo algunas preguntas del foro de OX aquí, esta es: https://sourceforge.net/p/openxava/discussion/419690/thread/d1aed7619c/